# Power analysis for correlated data points

Tags: simulation, statistical-power, generalized-least-squares

I want to using simulation to determine the effect size that could be detected with my sample size. What makes the simulation a bit complicated is that my dataset is about species traits. It means data points are not independent of each other.
The function I used to get the coefficient in the first place is phylolm from the package phylolm.

```
simple_mod <- phylolm(log_GS ~ proxy_scaled + PL, data = df_tmp3, 
                      phy = target_tree, model = "BM", boot = 10000)
mod_summary <- summary(simple_mod)
coefficient <- mod_summary$coefficients["proxy_scaled", 
                                        c("Estimate", "p.value", 
                                          "lowerbootCI", "upperbootCI")]
```

ChatGPT provided a solution like the following:

```
# Assuming your dataframe is named "df_tmp3"
sample_size <- nrow(df_tmp3)
num_simulations <- 1000  # Adjust the number of simulations as needed
alpha <- 0.05
true_effect_size <- 0.2  # Set your desired true effect size

# Fit the original phylolm model using actual data
original_mod <- phylolm(log_GS ~ proxy_scaled + PL, data = df_tmp3, 
                        phy = target_tree, model = "BM", boot = 10000)

# Extract the coefficient and p-value for proxy_scaled from the original model
original_coef <- original_mod$coefficients["proxy_scaled", "Estimate"]
original_p_value <- original_mod$coefficients["proxy_scaled", "p.value"]

# Create a vector to store the simulated p-values
simulated_p_values <- numeric(num_simulations)

# Run the simulation loop
for (i in 1:num_simulations) {
  # Generate random noise (residuals) for Y based on the true effect size
  simulated_Y <- original_mod$fitted.values + true_effect_size * rnorm(sample_size)
  
  # Create a temporary data frame with simulated Y
  simulated_data <- data.frame(log_GS = simulated_Y, proxy_scaled = df_tmp3$proxy_scaled, PL = df_tmp3$PL)
  
  # Fit the phylolm model using simulated data
  simulated_mod <- phylolm(log_GS ~ proxy_scaled + PL, data = simulated_data, 
                           phy = target_tree, model = "BM", boot = 10000)
  
  # Extract the p-value for proxy_scaled from the simulated model
  simulated_p_value <- simulated_mod$coefficients["proxy_scaled", "p.value"]
  
  # Store the simulated p-value
  simulated_p_values[i] <- simulated_p_value
}

# Calculate the proportion of simulations with significant p-values
proportion_significant <- sum(simulated_p_values < alpha) / num_simulations
```

I wonder if it is correct to randomly generate noise (residuals) for the dependent variable (log_GS) while keeping the predictors proxy_scaled and PL constant for my purpose. What I often see is people randomly generate the predictors, not the random noise for the dependent variable.
If anyone has any ideas or clues on this, I would greatly appreciate your input. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to CV, Emma! Good to look critical at GPT output ;-) Two questions: are errors in in phylogenetic models correlated (sorry, I don't know about these models)? And are they normal distributed? If no to any of these questions, you could already get suspicious of `...+true_effect_size * rnorm(sample_size)`. Otherwise I think it is OK to keep the predictors fixed when they are fixed in the model (if phylolm models work like ordinary lm models)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Ute! While I don't have a definitive answer to your questions, I do think the errors are somehow related. I came across a tutorial that mentioned "we do not expect the residual error to be normal - but rather multivariate normal with a correlation structure given by our input correlation structure of the model-fitting procedure." They then transformed the residuals like this: `transformed_residuals <- chol(solve(vcv(primate.tree))) %*% residuals(fitted.model)`.
From my understanding, phylolm works similarly to lm, but it accounts for correlations between residuals.

Comment: After some back and forth, ChatGPT now suggested to generate correlated residuals by using the mvrnorm() function.

`cov_matrix <- vcv(primate.tree); correlated_residuals <- mvrnorm(n = sample_size, mu = rep(0, sample_size), Sigma = cov_matrix); simulated_Y <- original_mod$fitted.values + true_effect_size * correlated_residuals`

The rest of the simulation process remains the same.

Comment: Interesting. The moral of the story: don't rely on GPT...

Comment: Agree.... The more I use GPT the more I feel it not trustful 